# Lilypond not automatically starting a new row of bars when lyrics and music too long to fit on single line

Tags: lilypond

I have the following script:

```
\version "2.16.0"
\header {title = "He came down"}
upper = \relative c'' {
    \easyHeadsOn
    \clef treble
    \key g \major
    \numericTimeSignature
    \time 4/4
    %He came down that we may have love;
    d,8 <d g>4  <d g> <d b'> <c a'> <d g> <fis a> <d c>2 r8
    %He came down that we may have love;
    <d c>8 <d a'>4 <d a'> <e c'> <d b'> <c a'> <d b'> <b g'>2 r8
    %He came down that we may have love;
    <b g'>8 <d b'>4 <d b> <g d'> <g c> <g b> <g c> g2
    %Hal -- le -- lu -- Yah for ev -- er -- more.


}

lower = \relative c {
    \clef bass
    \key g \major
    \time 4/4 
    d8
}

text = \lyricmode {
    He came down that we may have love;
    He came down that we may have love;
    He came down that we may have love;
    Hal -- le -- lu -- Yah for ev -- er -- more.
}

\score {
    \new GrandStaff <<
      \new Staff = upper {\new Voice = "singer" \upper }
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto "singer" \text
      \new Staff = lower { \lower }
    >>
}
```

Unfortunately when I compile it in Lilypond I get the following output:
[image]
Does anyone know how I can get Lilypond to typeset this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a programming issue, your problem is that you are adding too many notes to your 4/4 time signature. LilyPond has problems deciding when to add line breaks if the rhythms are exceeding the bar allowance (normally a score not line breaking is a red flag for rhythm problems). You can also add bar checks to your code using `|`. When using those, LilyPond will check if a bar line coincides with the bar rest position, and if there is a problem an error will be output, telling you exactly where the bar check does not coincide with the bar line.

Here is a fixed version of your code, though I am not sure this is the rhythm you intended or not:

```
\version "2.16.0"
\header {title = "He came down"}
upper = \relative c'' {
    \easyHeadsOn
    \clef treble
    \key g \major
    \numericTimeSignature
    \time 4/4
    %He came down that we may have love;
    d,8 <d g>4  <d g> <d b'> <c a'>8 | <d g>4 <fis a> <d c>2 | 
    %He came down that we may have love;
    <d c>8 <d a'>4 <d a'> <e c'> <d b'>8 | <c a'>4 <d b'> <b g'>2 |
    %He came down that we may have love;
    <b g'>8 <d b'>4 <d b> <g d'>8 <g c>4 | <g b> <g c> g2 |
    %Hal -- le -- lu -- Yah for ev -- er -- more.


}

lower = \relative c {
    \clef bass
    \key g \major
    \time 4/4 
    d8
}

text = \lyricmode {
    He came down that we may have love;
    He came down that we may have love;
    He came down that we may have love;
    Hal -- le -- lu -- Yah for ev -- er -- more.
}

\score {
    \new GrandStaff <<
      \new Staff = upper {\new Voice = "singer" \upper }
      \new Lyrics \lyricsto "singer" \text
      \new Staff = lower { \lower }
    >>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is just the upbeat that prevents lilypond from detecting the correct rythm. Just add a \partial 8 (this is the length of the upbeat).

```
\version "2.16.0"
\header {title = "He came down"}
upper = \relative c'' {
    \easyHeadsOn
    \clef treble
    \key g \major
    \numericTimeSignature
    \time 4/4

    \partial 8   % **This marks the upbeat. The length is 8, matching d,8 below** 

    %He came down that we may have love;
    d,8 <d g>4  <d g> <d b'> <c a'>8 | <d g>4 <fis a> <d c>2 | 
    ...
```